# How can the Number Field Sieve attack the discrete log in $\mathbb Z_p^*$ of DSA?

Tags: signature, discrete-logarithm, dsa, factoring

The [Digital Signature Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) (DSA) uses  $L$-bit prime $p$ and $N$-bit prime $q$  with $q| p-1$, i.e., $p = r\cdot q +1$ ( Schnorr group if $r>2$ and safe prime if $r=2$).

In a way, the security of DSA relies on the hardness of the discrete logarithm on $\mathbb{Z}^*_q$ that is given by $ y = g^x  \bmod \mathbb{Z}^*_q$ to find the $x$. This explains the choice of the size of $q$ on the standards, due to the [generic discrete log attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76241/18298) that have cost $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{q})$.

DSA uses $p$ as a huge prime compared to $q$, [NIST SP 800-57 Part 1 Revision 5](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r5.pdf).

- (L = 3072, N = 256),(L = 7680, N = 384), or (L = 15360, N = 512)

I've searched for the reason behind the large $p$, but couldn't find an explanation--neither the NIST documents nor the RFCs offer an explanation. I've only seen [Poncho's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/13165/18298).

> Use the [Number Field Sieve algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_field_sieve) to attack the discrete log problem in $Z^∗/p$. NFS is typically seen as a way to attack the factorization problem; it can also be applied (with some additional complexity) to compute discrete logs.

How can the Number Field Sieve algorithm be used to attack the discrete logarithm in $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ of DSA?

Comment: Relates to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/35574/555), which unfortunately has received no answer. I wish I knew!

Comment: @fgrieu we will learn, I hope.

Comment: I don't really know about NFS but I was told that the justification for the large $p$ is the **function field sieve** by Adleman *et al*. Which has complexity $\exp[(1+o(1))(32/9)^{1/3}(\log p)^{1/3}(\log\log p)^{2/3}]$ that is sub-exponential in $\log p$. That would justify the need for $3072$ bits for $p$  and $256$ bits for $q$ when targeting $128$ bits security. But I am not really certain...

Comment: The number field sieve, as applied to discrete logarithms, is an advanced form of index calculus. [One of my old answers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1389/592) describes how it works, at a high level.